# Hadoop 2.6.5 Installation in ubuntu16.04LTS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I had installed Hadoop 2.6.5 in ubuntu16.04LTS using Documentation . When i am running the data node i am getting the following error.

> 2018-06-10 12:53:17,866 WARN
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Invalid
>   dfs.datanode.data.dir /usr/local/hadoop_strore/hdfs/datanode : 
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File
>   file:/usr/local/hadoop_strore/hdfs/datanode does not exist
>
> 2018-06-10 12:53:17,880 FATAL
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in
>   secureMain java.io.IOException: All directories in
>   dfs.datanode.data.dir are invalid:
>   "/usr/local/hadoop_strore/hdfs/datanode"      at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:2354)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2327)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2219)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2266)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2442)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2466)
>   2018-06-10 12:53:17,883 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting
>   with status 1 2018-06-10 12:53:17,886 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:

Can someone please let me know what it is doing internally.
I have gone through these posts but there is no correct explanation

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>1</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
      <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
      <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please put the configuration in the *question*, not in a comment, where it's illegible. Here's my guess: `file:/usr/local/hadoop_strore` doesn't exist. Perhaps you spelled it correctly elsewhere?

Comment: did you check if the path `:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode` exists in your filesystem?

Comment: Typo? `hadoop_strore` should be `hadoop_store`??

Comment: Try removing "file:" from your dir path. If not, then try this: file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/name as suggested : [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml)